# Unit testing a control behaviour

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

In my C# project I have a method that get a `Control` and clear what's inside it.

```
public static void ClearText(Control con)
    {
        foreach (Control c in con.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
                ((TextBox)c).Clear();
            else if (c is ComboBox)
            {
                if (((ComboBox) c).DataSource != null)
                    ((ComboBox) c).DataSource = null;
                else
                    ((ComboBox) c).Items.Clear();
            }
            else if (c is CheckBox)
                ((CheckBox) c).Checked = false;
            else
                ClearAllText(c);
        }
    }
```

This code works ok, now I'm trying to create some unit test for it. I've tried this path and it seems ok:

- Create new object (TextBox,Checkbox...)
- Call `ClearText`
- Check (Assert) if the created object's text property is empty.

This implies reference to `Windows.Forms`, is there any way to accomplish this ? Maybe using some way of `Mocking` ?

Comment: You cant uniy-test UI Controls, test only logic associated with the UI Controls. You need to follow the MVP pettern for Winform/ MVVM pattern for WPF to do unit testing properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the sample code in your question, I don't see any concerns about writing a unit test to exercise this utility function. There isn't anything specific about it that would require a mocking framework.

```
[TestMethod]
public void WhenClearingTextOnAControl_AndControlContainsNestedCheckboxes_ShouldClearCheckedBoxes()
{
    // arrange: create a control hierarchy
    var input = new Panel();
    var insidePanel = new Panel();
    var checkbox = new Checkbox();
    input.Controls.Add(insidePanel);
    insidePanel.Controls.Add(checkbox);
    checkbox.Checked = true;

    // act: invoke our function
    _subject.ClearText(input);

    // assert
    Assert.IsFalse(checkbox.Checked, "Inner checkbox should have been cleared.");
}
```